# Positioning one element completely center on same level as element positioned on the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know questions similar have been discussed frequently but I can't find an answer to my current issue:

```css
.above-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
}

.below-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="above-content">Text in the middle</div>
<div class="below-content">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <button>Button that should be right aligned</button>
</div>
```

I have a div that includes an indicator and a button, the button should be positioned to the right and the indicator to the center.

I can use `flex: 1` on the indicator but this then causes the indicator to grow to take up the full available space: I need a solution that means that the indicator is exactly center at all times & the button is positioned to the right, regardless of whether or not either may or may not be present.

I do not want the indicator to only be center of the available space (remaining from the button width).

Comment: You should provide a visual of what you expect/want to do

Comment: Hopefully my OP outlines the issue. Button should be positioned to the right - indicator should be completely center (not just center of space left by button).

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: I can modify the HTML 

Comment: Is absolute positioning of the button an option? or worried that there could be some overlap?

Comment: Was hoping to achieve with Flex, but maybe not possible.

Comment: This kind of behaviour may only be possible when the button is not in the *normal flow*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wrapper around your button, then use a pseudo-element to fill in the left column:

```html
<div class="above-content">Text in the middle</div>
<div class="below-content">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button>Button that should be right aligned</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.below-content::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.below-content::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: end;
}

/* Original styles */

.above-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
}

.below-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="above-content">Text in the middle</div>
<div class="below-content">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button>Button that should be right aligned</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use grid and let it takes care of the rest:

```css
.below-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.indicator {
  grid-column: 2;
}

button {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.below-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.indicator {
  grid-column: 2;
}

button {
  justify-self: end;
}

/* Original styles */

.above-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
}

.below-content {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="above-content">Text in the middle</div>
<div class="below-content">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <button>Button that should be right aligned</button>
</div>
```